# Await database before register queue using nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I need to get database value before register using nestjs/bull package, how can I achieve this?

```
@Module({
imports: [
  /* Db Import */
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TransactionRepository]),
  BullModule.registerQueueAsync(
    {
      name: `${GlobalService.namespace}:${GlobalService.QUEUE_DELIVERY}`,
      useFactory: async () => { 
        const data = await initQueue(getManager()) // get data from typeorm getManager not working
        return {
          limiter: {
            max: Number(data.CALLBACK_TPS),
            duration: 1000,
          }
        }
      },
    },
  ),
],
controllers: [ApiController],
providers: [ApiService, ResponseApiUtil],
})
```

This is error code

```
    [Nest] 1465026  - 03/20/2022, 3:10:23 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Connection is not established with mysql database
TypeORMError: Connection is not established with mysql database
```

Comment: Why not inject the connection via `inject: [getConnectionToken()]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the connection to the factory using `inject: [getConnectionToken()]` like

```js
@Module({
imports: [
  /* Db Import */
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TransactionRepository]),
  BullModule.registerQueueAsync(
    {
      name: `${GlobalService.namespace}:${GlobalService.QUEUE_DELIVERY}`,
      inject: [getConnectionToken()],
      useFactory: async (connection: Connection) => { 
        const data = await initQueue(connection.getManager())
        return {
          limiter: {
            max: Number(data.CALLBACK_TPS),
            duration: 1000,
          }
        }
      },
    },
  ),
],
controllers: [ApiController],
providers: [ApiService, ResponseApiUtil],
})
```